# How to use XSLT as template engine in Spring?

Tags: spring-mvc, xslt

My action in controller:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String get(Model model){

        String xml="<items>" +
                "<item><name>James</name></item>"+
                "<item><name>Luck</name></item>"+
                "<item><name>Luck</name></item>"+
                "</items>";
        
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document=builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

        model.addAttribute("items",document.getDocumentElement());
        
        return "item";
    }
```

My xslt file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>RSS22 Au format HTML</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Affichage de la liste des articles stockés</h1>
                <div>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <th>name</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/> </td>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the problem is that the generated view contains plain text

Comment: It seems your code (controller) does not use the xslt file at all, or your code is incomplete.

Comment: I created a configuration class